# Extract numbers from String Array in Scala

Tags: string, scala

I'm new to Scala and unsure of how to achieve the following

I have the String

```
val output = "6055039\n3000457596\n3000456748\n180013\n"
```

I want to extract the numbers separated by \n and store them in an Array

Comment: `output.split("\n").map(_.toInt)`

But this isn't really a good question for SO. Please read this page for future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output.split("\n").map(_.toInt)
```

Or only

```
output.split("\n")
```

if you want to keep the numbers in String format. Note that `.toInt` throws. You might want to wrap it accordingly.

Comment: thanks, I ended up using toLong as I have Long numbers as well